# System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting missing error in .net 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use the Chart control in asp.net 4.0.  While I know it required a separate install as part of 3.5, it's included by default with 4.0.

I can see the Chart control in my toolbox, and I can drag it to my designer and see a preview of the chart.  However, when I try to compile my website, I get an error stating:

> The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I receive the same error when I take a brand new page and add the following:

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization;
```

Any ideas?  I can understand why I would get this error in 3.5, but no clue why I would receive in 4.0, especially when I can see the control in the toolbox.

Comment: Can we create chart animation using same namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I upgraded my website from .net 3.5 to 4.0, some of the references in my web.config didn't automatically get updated to 4.0. After I manually updated them, everything worked.

Answer (score 31):

Click on Add References in your project and in the .NET Components tab **add the System.Web.DataVisualization**. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Downvote because I have this same problem, but the references are already added. -> Update: My mistake. Upvoting instead.

Answer (score 10):

Click on **Add References** in your project and Browse to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` and add the `System.Web.DataVisualization dll` file.

Before adding the dll remove the previous one and make sure that change the Target Frameweok to V4.0 in the project properties.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: What if I don't have the `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll` file in my `...\v4.0`? I only have loads of .xml files and there's no a single one with the name `DataVisualization`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in `Program Files\Microsoft Chart Controls\Assemblies` .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference and then add reference again.

Comment: Can we create chart animation using same namespace?

Answer (score -3):

In case you missed, just add the `System.Web.Extensions` reference to your project, and it will solve your problems.